# Bounded projetions in Banach spaces admits closed range

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $P:X\rightarrow X$ a linear operator such that $P^2=P$.

Then $P$ bounded if and only if $PX$ and $(1-P)X$ is closed.

I dont know how to proceed for this direction: $P$ is bounded, then $PX$ and $(1-P)X$ are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1 - P)X$ is the kernel of $P$. Indeed, $P(1 - P) = P - P^2 = 0$, so $(1 - P)X \subseteq ker(P)$. Conversely, for any $x \in ker(P)$, $x = x - Px = (1 - P)x$. Thus, as $P$ is bounded, $(1 - P)X = ker(P)$ is closed. Similarly, $1 - P$ is easily seen to be a bounded projection as well, so $PX = [1 - (1 - P)]X = ker(1 - P)$ is also closed.